# Does anybody know another way to create join table migration and specify a specific name of references columns in join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have these two models:

```
 module Studying
  class Student < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :instructors,
                        class_name: 'Studying::Instructor',
                        foreign_key: 'studying_student_id',
                        association_foreign_key: 'studying_instructor_id'
  end
end


 module Studying
  class Instructor < ApplicationRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :students,
                        class_name: 'Studying::Student',
                        foreign_key: 'studying_instructor_id',
                        association_foreign_key: 'studying_student_id'
  end
end
```

And for join_table I have generated migration:

```
def change
  create_table :studying_instructors_students, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :studying_instructor, index: { name: 'index_instructors_students_on_studying_instructor_id' }
  t.belongs_to :studying_student, index: { name: 'index_instructors_students_on_studying_student_id' }
  end
end
```

So all is working fine, but the point is, that my senior comrade tells me that I should not use in models things such as:

```
  foreign_key:  'studying_instructor_id',
```

and

```
  association_foreign_key: 'studying_student_id'
```

but instead of these I should use:

```
  foreign_key:  'instructor_id',
```

and

```
  association_foreign_key: 'student_id'
```

and in the same way in the first model because this is against the convention.
I do not know how I can do this in this models and in tables (how you already understand tables names in db: studying_instructors and  studying_students).

Any advice please ?

Comment: Thank you  Martin Evans, that  checked my spelling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create relation table this way

```
def change
  create_table :studying_instructors_students, id: false do |t|
    t.integer :instructor_id, index: true
    t.integer :student_id, index: true
  end
end
```

and then you can use  `foreign_key:  'instructor_id',`  and  `association_foreign_key: 'student_id'`

If I get this wrong way, please, feel free to address additional questions.

Comment: Thank you!  it is works perfect.  solution looks easy ))

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
class Studying::Student < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :student_instructors, class_name: 'Studying::StudentInstructor'
  has_many :instructors, through: :student_instructors, class_name: 'Studying::Instructor'

end

class Studying::Instructor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :student_instructors, class_name: 'Studying::StudentInstructor'
  has_many :students, through: :student_instructors, class_name: 'Studying::Instructor'      
end

class Studying::StudentInstructor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student, class_name: 'Studying::Student'
  belongs_to :instructor, class_name: 'Studying::Instructor'      
end
```

I have three tables here. One for students, second for instructors and third one is a junction table (student_instructors).

Migration for studnt_instructor will look something like this

```
def change
  create_table :student_instuctors, id: false do |t|
    t.integer :instructor_id, index: true
    t.integer :student_id, index: true
  end
end
```

I have not verified the syntax but this is more of logic explanation.

I hope this helps.